# Где у Windows(XP) требовать ввода пароля?

Tags: администрирование, пароль, windows-xp

Доброго всем здравия. С самого начала с WinXP и ни чего в ней не понимаю. http://lh3.ggpht.com/-divrcOqP-h0/UaxjmK4ez8I/AAAAAAAABvI/N-UUVyHMBV8/s0/img8e416bb7b5d8c4f8021c89154e9a721f.jpg. Где этот checkbox? (отмеченный красным). Он вообще в природе существует и у кого? О себе: [Windows XP x86, версия движка 5.1, сборка 2600.xpsp`_`sp3`_`qfe.130704-0421 SP3]

P.S. Не репак и не сборная от всяких зверей и животных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Буду краток [http://social.technet.microsoft.com](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/31d0236d-4101-4ad1-87fb-512740f2ac73/control-userpasswords2)

Comment: первыя ссылка в гугле - https://www.google.ru/search?q=control+userpasswords2

Comment: Буду краток - недели 3 назад, как раз завёл в Домен.  Спасибо!